# What is the largest amateur satellite in orbit through 2014?

Tags: satellites

What is the largest, and what were the dimensions of the largest amateur radio designated satellite in Earth orbit as of, or up until, 2014 other than the International space station.

Comment: I take it "[Luna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)" is not the answer you're looking for, even though it can be [used for amateur radio communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Moon-Earth_communication)?

Comment: The word launch discourages that...

Comment: I'm also going to assume not the ISS, as that isn't its prime function...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Ironically, the OP has edited out the word "launched" now.

Comment: What does OP stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my sources, the 3 biggest Amateur Radio satellites (By Radar Cross Section) are:

- International Space Station
- Oceansat 1- Had a small Amateur Radio payload
- [AO-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AO-40) Dedicated Amateur Radio satellite.